# R: Calculate Markov transition matrix when sequences are of unequal lengths

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have several stand-alone observed sequences of different length called `movs` and would like to calculate a general transition matrix for movs. There are two problems:

1. Not all states appear in each sequence.
2. I cannot concatenate them.

   df<-data.frame(activityID=rep(1:4,c(10,5,4,1))),movs=sample(c("A","B","C"),20,replace=T))

I've looked at the package `markovchain` which has a function `markovchainfit` and an argument `possibleStates` which allows me to pre-define all the states that will exist in the sequence even if they do not appear in all of them.
https://rdrr.io/a/cran/markovchain/man/markovchainFit.html

But because the sequences aren't in rows and because they are of different lengths  I convert df to a list:

```
d<-split(df$movs, df$activityID)
```

Then run `markovfitlist` but it doesn't have the `possibleStates` argument.

```
markovchain::markovchainListFit(data = d,byrow = F)
```

So now I have a transition matrix for each sequence - **How do I combine them all to make 1 transition matrix that includes all the states?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyEMMA (Python based) for this purpose, it first combines all sequences in a count matrix. This matrix gives the transition counts for each pair of states and is then fed into a transition matrix estimator.
Probably the same thing is possible for this R package you are using, since it is a quite common task.

Comment: Hi marscher, thank you for this. Ideally I would like to stay in R. There is a package called markovchain which in theory can do what I'm after, but I cannot find a way of feeding it sequences of unequal lengths and missing states to create 1 global transition matrix. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculate-transition-matrix-markov-in-r